# как растянуть div во всю ширину контейнера c overflow-x: scroll

Tags: html, css

```css
.p1 {width:300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;  overflow-x: scroll;}
.p2 {height: 30px; background: #902457;  display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="p1">
  <p>204204204200420424204204204420420420420420420000420</p>
  <div class="p2"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ghb3ahc/12/

P.s Знаю, что такой вопрос и подобные вопросы уже задавали, но решения я не нашел

Comment: не представляю если чесно зачем вам ето но можно задать ширину div { width: max-content; }

Comment: мой заказчик учиться в айти школе, и там такое задание).  width: max-content; не сработало

Comment: странно, запустил, вроде работает, может мы не так поняли ваш вопрос

Comment: Он должен визуально прокручиваться при скролле или это просто визуальный элемент?

Answer (score 1):

В принципе сработает такое, хотя это и не то, о чём говорится в вопросе:

```css
.p1 {width:300px; height: 180px; border: 1px solid #000;  overflow-x: scroll;}
.p2 {height: 30px; background: #902457;  display: block;}

.p2 {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="p1">
  <p>204204204200420424204204204420420420420420420000420</p>
  <div class="p2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.p1 {width:300px; height: 180px; border: 1px solid #000;  overflow-x: scroll;}
.p2 {height: 30px; background: #902457;  display: block;}

.p1 {
  display: grid;
  align-content: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="p1">
  <p>204204204200420424204204204420420420420420420000420</p>
  <div class="p2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

p2 добавить width такую как у родителя (в нашем случае 300px), и добавить для p2 position fixed